# How AutoFill password functionality in iOS app? Do i need to do any changes in my app if i want to add it?

Tags: ios11, swift4, xcode9

I am not sure is autofill password functionality is totally iOS feature or developer will have to add some standard code to to use it?

Comment: You can have a quick look at [Introducing Password AutoFill for Apps](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/206/) - WWDC video

Answer (score 0):

It works automatically for `UITextField`s with `UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress` type and enables `secureTextEntry` property. I checked it in an app released last autumn. Key button appears above the keyboard, asks of Touch ID on tap and presents keychain items. I was surprised, it fills related email and password to two text fields. Works like a charm!

**Update**: I found great tutorial implementation this feature: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/faster-logins-with-password-autofill-in-ios-11--cms-29096. You can bind credentials saved from your site with the app directly.

[image: Screenshot of login form]

Comment: There seems to be no way to change the password from within the app itself (if password was changed at the site/service and the iCloud keychain still carries the old password). I guess you have to open Safari to be able to change the password, or/and do it from Settings. At least I can't do it in-app. Tested with iOS 11.0/iOS 11.4. Not tried with iOS 12 beta so far.